# Error parsing metadata using python datacatalog

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I'm trying to update attached tag to tables in data catalog using python : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2xZ6.png)

And i recieve this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtYtN.png)
E0102 16:29:36.671000000 13508 src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.cc:1228] Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value key=content-type value=text/html; charset=UTF-8

For creating tag template and attaching tag to tables, they work perfectly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi!, I want to ask you about this one, did you solved this? Attach Tag from Tag Templates to the BigQuery Table with python? Really appreciaty if you can answer my question, Thank you!

Comment: Hi, no I didn't solve the problem, do you face the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error comes from gRPC library when parsing response from Data Catalog server. There is a similar [bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/29706) reported. In the bug there is a suggestion that the gRPC client error may happen when Google Frontend server returns error.

It's hard to find the cause based on the attached error message and code snippet. To debug the problem I recommend:

- Printing tag content and credentials from the application and doing the request from command line (e.g. with [grpc_cli](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md#call-a-remote-method) or via REST API with curl) to see if some error is returned from the server.
- Alternatively, using some transport proxy (Wireshark, Fiddler, or similar) to see passed messages and responses.
- Downgrading gRPC library to the version where the header parsing error isn't logged until the problem is fixed.